# How to draw a line between static view's center points to google map marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a static Linear layout and a google map in my xml file. I want to draw a straight line between center bottom of linear layout to the marker position.I have tried using polylines in the maps but it is also drawing between markers in the maps.
Below is my xml file -

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_m1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_ll"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            tools:context="com.business.introslider.MapsActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/pickup_ll"
            android:onClick="OpenPickup"
            android:elevation="30dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pickup from"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#555555"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/s_green"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pin location"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/text_pickup_location"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and also my java code is as below -

```
public void setCurrentLocation(){
        try {
            //to show my current location in the map

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), latLng.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            //to request location updates
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);
            ViewTreeObserver vto = pickup_ll.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        pickup_ll.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        pickup_ll.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                    float x = pickup_ll.getX() + pickup_ll.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
                    float y = pickup_ll.getY() + pickup_ll.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;

                //    float x= getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2;
                    point1 = new Point(Math.round(x),Math.round(y));
                    Log.e(TAG, "point1===" + point1);
                    LatLng latLng1 = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(point1);
                    Log.e(TAG,"latLng1==="+latLng1);
                    points.add(latLng1);
                }

            });

 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onlocation changed");
        //To clear map data
        mMap.clear();
        //To hold location
        if(latLng !=null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "latLng onlocation changed==" + latLng);
        }
        else {
            latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        }
        //to create a marker in the app
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("My Location");
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
        polylineOptions.width(2);
        points.add(latLng);
        polylineOptions.addAll(points);
        mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //opening position with some zoom level in the app
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17.0f));
    }
```

I am calling this setCurrentLocation() in onMapReady method of googleApiClient. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you trying to do drawing path in this way?
https://github.com/hiepxuan2008/GoogleMapDirectionSimple/
this will let you to draw a path between tow places. Make sure you change the API key.

Comment: This link hadn't turned out to be useful for me.